# How can I make my point of view or critic on topic?

Tags: support

Say I watch a movie but I did not like the ending.

Can I post a question to evaluate my preferred ending to that movie?

Or do I just post a question to say my reasons why that movie shouldn't have ended the way it did? Then that would just get a Yes or NO answer right?

Basically I'm asking are reviews of a movie ok? movie critics ok?

Comment: Asking WHY the movie ended the way it did vs an alternative ending could be acceptable if you state facts clearly enough that it's an analysis question instead of an opinion question

Comment: That will be opinion based and will surely get closed or atleast i will post a close vote. No offence but it didn't fit with the sites structure.

Comment: @AnkitSharma No, if phrased properly there is perfect room for the significance/effect/use of a rather unexpected ending compared to a more conformant or intuitive ending. Provided with some proper objective reasoning the subjectivity of such evaluations can be mitigated to a large degree (assuming your comment was a reply to *DustinDavis*'s, whom I can only agree with).

Comment: @NapoleonWilson my reply is to the question

Comment: Sounds like you should start a blog.

Answer (score 4):

I'd be interested in hearing other's opinions, but I think it would be difficult to ask a question that was a review of a movie or asking for thoughts on a subjectively better ending.

This is not a 'forum' - a place for open ended opinionated discussion - StackExchange is a Question and Answer platform, and expects questions to be looking for reasonably objectively correct answers.

Clearly for the 'soft' subjects like Movies & TV or Science Fiction & Fantasy the answers can be somewhat more subjective, but I would pose that the limit that we usually stick to here is 'analysis' - i.e. its perfectly ok to ask "why" something happened in a movie and expect to see various opinions, backed by observations from the movie.